# PCB-mount DC to AC inverter

Tags: inverter, sourcing

Folks,

As you know, there are small PCB-mounted AC to DC power supplies.  Some of them are encapsulated “bricks”, and some are open frame.  I’m looking for a small (12W or so) DC to AC inverter in a similar PCB-mount form factor.  Have anyone seen something like that in their travels?

Any suggestion, insight or reference is really appreciated!

I could build my own inverter with a [small transformer (like this one)](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-PB/4900-8012RD63/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvwUzoUXIIvybxvWcHlXqMIocJ0Xi7K%252bHc=) and a handful of other components.  That would be my fallback variant, if I can’t buy a module.

Cheers,
- Nick

Comment: You say DC-AC twice and AC-DC once. Before the shopping list bovver boys come you may wish to say what you ACTUALLY want, if AC-DC as probable is it 110 AC-DC or 110-240 universal or ? What VDC. More info better answer. Clock ticks. Boots heard in hallway ... . 
IF AC DC there are a zillion plugpacks with boards in. Is this 1/small/1000/1M volume?

Comment: @Russell McMahon  "DC-AC twice and AC-DC once." This reminds me of a former client, who said that people can't read a document containing more than 1 drawing.  I don't assume electronics.stackexchange members are stupid.

Comment: @Russell McMahon  To quote my original post: "I’m looking for a small (12W or so) DC to AC inverter"  Original post title: "PCB-mount DC to AC inverter"  As you may have guessed, I'm loking for a PCB-mount DC to AC inverter.  If you can post something useful about PCB-mount DC to AC inverter in quantities of 1 (one), I'd appreciate that.  Same for quantities of 1M (one million) and anything in between.

Comment: I've learned from years of getting it wrong that when what people ask for is not crystal clear to me then I may well misunderstand what is really wanted :-). If the question has potential for ambiguity I find it is often worth clarifying. Not always.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, There is an issue here, as russell noted, there are some things that are considered good shopping and some that are considered bad shopping questions. If you would just like a list of modules to choose from then the site is acting as a google for you that will go out of date and is not of long term value. If you would like to learn about how to find DC to AC inverters answers that teach you how to shop for them, teaching you things such as important parameters and then give you links to example devices as side information are very valuable. Which is it that you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Answer rather than comment as refs take up vast room:

Any number of small units who innards would almost meet your spec BUT at 75W up.

Many DIY ccts as you know.

**Of these many I'd note**

[This](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/28656115/Simple-12-to-230V-Power-Inverter)  due to the use of the nice SGS3526N IC

[This](http://electroniccircuitsdiagram.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/pure-sine-wave-inverter-schematic.gif) for its output filter. note that they use a multistep PWM waveform to emulate sine wave - see [original paper](http://www.kmitl.ac.th/~kswichit%20/didik/sineinverter.pdf)

[This](http://www.google.co.nz/imgres?q=inverter+12vdc+110+vac&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1920&bih=1068&tbm=isch&tbnid=jfSwniRniSyRIM%3a&imgrefurl=http://inverter-circuit.com/40w-inverter-circuit-12vdc-to-110220vac.html/40w-inverter-circuit-diagram&docid=ghII04TDaP5n_M&imgurl=http://inverter-circuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/40W-Inverter-Circuit-Diagram.jpg&w=715&h=295&ei=luIHT4nwHIiKmQW6q6DABw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1503&vpy=784&dur=2356&hovh=144&hovw=350&tx=186&ty=90&sig=105250506097979753968&page=1&tbnh=69&tbnw=168&start=0&ndsp=60&ved=1t:429,r:18,s:0) or [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_TXBMxL7E6Ts/Swsh5ynVOUI/AAAAAAAAAe0/IpA0GBoFahc/s1600/RANGKAIAN+CONVERTER+AC+12VDC-220VAC.gif) for idea of using 4047 - use FETs in place of bipolars.

[This](http://www.google.co.nz/imgres?q=inverter+12vdc+110+vac&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1920&bih=1068&tbm=isch&tbnid=r-YGBQSNirwm0M%3a&imgrefurl=http://circuitpowersupply.blogspot.com/2009/12/12-vdc-to-120-vac-inverter-circuit.html&docid=Oz65aU5FsH99bM&imgurl=http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_TXBMxL7E6Ts/Sx1aBevvTJI/AAAAAAAAAic/j6h9_PdBJUk/s400/12%252BVDC%252Bto%252B120%252BVAC%252BInverter%252BCircuit.gif&w=400&h=400&ei=luIHT4nwHIiKmQW6q6DABw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=510&vpy=371&dur=798&hovh=225&hovw=225&tx=105&ty=105&sig=105250506097979753968&page=4&tbnh=133&tbnw=136&start=188&ndsp=61&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:188) as example of olde style super simple. Use MOSFETs BUT note effect base characteristics on timing.

[This as example of commercial 75W module with a smaller PCB inside](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/11777/209770553-459886361/Bestwit-Car-75W-12V-DC-to-110V-AC-super-thin-Power-Inverter-Adapter-HK118.html) - too large but ...

Comment: There's more info on DIY inverters posted by Russell in this thread: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18750/building-an-inverter-to-charge-various-devices .  Thanks, Russell!

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking to convert 12 V DC to 110 V AC (there seems to be some confusion in your question), then yes these are readily available at low cost. They are generally used to power 110 V appliances from a car.

[Inverter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_%28electrical%29) from Wikipedia & some [examples](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=inverter&x=0&y=0).

As for making one, a transformer by itself will not convert DC to AC. There is virtually no way you could construct a one off unit cheaper than you could buy one.